# I want to write the regex expression for the following text

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the text of this format:

**1ST Circuit U.S. District Court for NEW YORK SOUTHERN District Judge SMITH, JOHN T., JR**

In the text, I want to capture:

**Circuit name:** In the example above, 1ST CIRCUIT. Circuit number can be between 1ST and 99TH. This information is not always there.

**State name:** In the text above, NEW YORK SOUTHERN. It can be at most three words. This information is not always there.

**Title:** It can be either District or Magistrate.

**Last Name:** Here, it is SMITH

**Name:** The name is JOHN T.,JR

To make my problem more clear, let me give two more examples of the text I want to parse.

**15TH Circuit U.S. District Court for ALABAMA Magistrate Judge NEELY, CATHERINE**

**Magistrate Judge COOKE, THOMAS M**

I have tried the following expression. It was able to capture the name of the judge but failed to capture the circuit and the state.

```
((?P<circuit>\d{1,2}\w{2} Circuit)?\s?(U\.S\. District Court for )?\s?(? 
P<state>\b[A-Z]*(\s[A-Z]*)\b)*)?.* (?<=Judge )(?P<lname>[A-Z]*), (?P<name> 
[A-Z,. ]*)( {1,2}\(.*\))?
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help.

```
import re


s = ["1ST Circuit U.S. District Court for NEW YORK SOUTHERN District Judge SMITH, JOHN T., JR", "15TH Circuit U.S. District Court for ALABAMA Magistrate Judge NEELY, CATHERINE"]

for sVal in s:
    m = re.search(r"((?P<circuit>\d*(ST|TH) Circuit)) U.S. District Court for (?P<state>\b[A-Z\s]*\b)(?P<title>(District|Magistrate)) Judge (?P<lname>[A-Z]*), (?P<name>.*$)", sVal)
    if m:
        for i in ["circuit", "state", "title", "lname", "name"]:
            print(m.group(i))
    print("-----")
```

**Output:**

```
1ST Circuit
NEW YORK SOUTHERN 
District
SMITH
JOHN T., JR
-----
15TH Circuit
ALABAMA 
Magistrate
NEELY
CATHERINE
-----
```